# Moving one repository branches to another remote repository in git

Tags: git

I've a remote repository (`AAA`) and clone of it on my machine (`Local_AAA`).
Now my repository is blocked and I want all of those local branches to be moved to a different remote repository (`BBB`).

I found a few solutions on web but none of them worked for me.

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your local repo works, you can simply change its `origin` and mirror push to `BBB` (if `BBB` is empty)

```
cd /path/to/Local_AAA
git remote set-url origin /url/to/BBB
git push --mirror
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Will try this now.